# Jax.rs: What is the zero-length representation of an object?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs

I have this issue:

We have a JAX.RS api like this:

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Path("get")
public User get(@QueryParam(value = "id") String identifier) {
    return toUser(getUserEntry(identifier));
}
```

The toUser() method can return null, which in practice means that the client will see a 204 - No Content response.

Now, on the client side my code looks like this:

```
getWebTarget("user")
            .path("get")
            .queryParam("id", identifier)
            .request(getMediaType())
            .get()
            .readEntity(SsoUser.class);
```

I was expecting the readEntity() to throw some kind of exception, but it actually returns null and does not complain.

Looking at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#readEntity-java.lang.Class-), I see this:

> for a zero-length response entities returns a corresponding Java object that represents zero-length data. **In case no zero-length representation is defined for the Java type**, a ProcessingException wrapping the underlying NoContentException is thrown.

So it appears that my `User` class does define a "zero-length representation". But I can't find anywhere in the documentation what this representation means.

I can understand how Java *might* infer that the zero-length representation is null, but I don't know where to define that.

Any insight on this?

Answer (score -2):

I may be wrong about this, but I don't think Jax-RS is capable of handling `null` values for You. What You could do is explicitly handling that case, e.g.

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Path("get")
public Response get(@QueryParam(value = "id") String identifier) {
    User maybeNull = toUser(getUserEntry(identifier));
    Response response = null;
    if(null == maybeNull) {
      response = Response.noContent().build();
    } else {       
      response = Response.ok(maybeNull).build();
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: A null entity is automatically sent with a NO_CONTENT response status.